# What is LinkedIn's "email challenges" feature?

Tags: protection

A [LinkedIn blog post](https://blog.linkedin.com/2016/05/18/protecting-our-members) about the [recent password dump](http://techcrunch.com/2016/05/18/117-million-linkedin-emails-and-passwords-from-a-2012-hack-just-got-posted-online/) says:

> We take the safety and security of our members' accounts seriously. For several years, we have hashed and salted every password in our database, and we have offered **protection tools such as email challenges** and dual factor authentication. We encourage our members to visit our safety center to learn about enabling two-step verification, and to use strong passwords in order to keep their accounts as safe as possible.

What is the "email challenges" security tool that they mention? I couldn't find anything relevant by searching their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a variation on two factor authentication that checks whether the user has access to their registered email address by emailing them a link containing a token. It is under the assumption that an attacker that has gained access to a LinkedIn account might not have gained access to the user's email inbox.

[See here](https://zeltser.com/what-anomalies-trigger-the-linkedin-sign-in/). Extract below.

> LinkedIn prompts users to take additional steps when it determines
>   that the logon attempt is unusual.  ... the service presents a
>   security challenge when the user attempts to sign-in “from an
>   unfamiliar location or device” or when the service detects “suspicious
>   web activity.” In this case, the user might be emailed a verification
>   link  ... The security challenge could come up when the user accesses
>   LinkedIn from a new country. In this case, the person would see:
>
> “This sign-in attempt seems unusual for you. As a security precaution,
>   please check your email to verify this sign-in attempt.”